# Create symbol from more than one path in Paperjs

Tags: javascript, paperjs

So, I'm trying to draw something in paperjs but the shape is a little more complex than just a square or a circle.

```
var path_tank_left_track = new Path({
  segments: [[0,0], [10, 0], [10,40], [0,40]], strokeColor: 'black',
  closed: true
});
var path_tank_right_track = new Path({
  segments: [[40,0], [50, 0], [50,40], [40,40]], strokeColor: 'black',
  closed: true
});

var path_tank_body = new Path({
  segments: [[10,5], [40,5], [40,35], [10,35]], strokeColor: 'black',
  closed: true
});

var path_tank_gun = new Path({
  segments: [[23,15], [23,0], [27, 0], [27, 15]],
  strokeColor: 'black',
  pivot: [25,15],
  name: 'gun'
});
```

This makes a little tank, for ease of modification, I grouped the all of these paths into a group like this :

```
var whole_tank = new Group(path_tank_left_track, path_tank_body,
  path_tank_right_track, path_tank_gun);
```

That works fine if I want only one tank. But I'd like to make more tanks and have them interact with each other.

I tried placing the paths into its own object and place them somewhere else. That didn't work.

I heard of Symbols, but it doesn't seem to take Groups as an argument :

```
var sym = Symbol(whole_tank);
```

Is there a way to properly create instances of multiples paths ? Or should I create a Symbol for each part of the tank and then group them together ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified [paper.js documentation about `SymbolDefintion`](http://paperjs.org/reference/symboldefinition/#symboldefinition-item) to create symbols from a `Group` and it works:

```
var path = new Path.Star(new Point(0, 0), 6, 5, 13);
path.style = {
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black'
};

var c = new Path.Circle(new Point(0, 0), 5);
c.fillColor = 'red';

var g = new Group();
g.addChild(path);
g.addChild(c);

// Create a symbol definition from the path:
var definition = new SymbolDefinition(g);

// Place 100 instances of the symbol definition:
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Place an instance of the symbol definition in the project:
    var instance = definition.place();

    // Move the instance to a random position within the view:
    instance.position = Point.random() * view.size;

    // Rotate the instance by a random amount between
    // 0 and 360 degrees:
    instance.rotate(Math.random() * 360);

    // Scale the instance between 0.25 and 1:
    instance.scale(0.25 + Math.random() * 0.75);
}
```

Working sketch [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

Note that you can also [rasterize](http://paperjs.org/reference/group/#rasterize) your `Group` and use the resulting image ; you could put those images in a div on top of the canvas and move them with css (or webgl ;-) ).

Comment: That worked ! Thank you ! I did not even know the SymbolDefinition existed ... IS there a way to give these symbols some properties that will be helpful with my code ? Like a speed or something ?

Comment: You can use the [Item.data](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#data) attribute to store custom properties. You can vote up the answer if you like it  ;-)

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet to upvote anything, but I did mark your reply as the answer ! Thanks again.